# Creating new print composer programmatically?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I would like to create a print composer (e.g. A3 landscape) containing a single map with a few lines of code. I do not need legends, labels, scale bars and so on.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your Question suggests that you want to replace the hole print composer instead of just creating a new map. I would recommend to edit your question.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question if there is something misleading or missing.

Comment: Doubt this answers your question fully, but this would be a starting point - http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is very *vague*, so (at least at this moment) I can only post a very general answer.

---

### Solution for QGIS 2.x

Supposing you want to create a new composition in which there is one map containing all the layers enabled in the Layers Panel, you may run the following code from the Python Console:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
# the following two libraries are needed only if you execute the code outside the Python Console (for example, from the Processing Toolbox)
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

map_settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
c = QgsComposition(map_settings)

view = iface.createNewComposer()
view.setComposition(c)

composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, 0 ,0, 420, 297)
# where the second and third parameters are customizable offsets (in mm) for positioning the composition (setting both 0 as values means that the rendering will start from the upper left corner of the composition)
# and the fourth and fifth parameters are the width and the height (in mm) for the A3 format
composerMap.setBackgroundEnabled(True)

rect = QgsRectangle(map_settings.fullExtent())
composerMap.setNewExtent(rect)
composerMap.updateItem()
c.addComposerMap(composerMap)

# all credits to Francisco Raga's answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/206463/87487) for the next code snippet:

# find items and items prop widget
win = view.composerWindow()
items_widget = win.findChildren(QDockWidget, 'ItemsDock')[0]

items_widget_prop = win.findChildren(QDockWidget, 'ItemDock')[0]
items_widget_prop.show()

# set items model
items_list_widget = items_widget.findChildren(QTreeView,'')[0]
items_model = c.itemsModel()
items_list_widget.setModel(items_model)

QObject.connect( items_list_widget.selectionModel(), SIGNAL("currentChanged( QModelIndex, QModelIndex)"), c.itemsModel(),SLOT("setSelected( QModelIndex )"))
```

and it will print the desired result.

---

### Solution for QGIS 3.x

According to the user's needs, I tried to find a working solution for QGIS 3.x and it worked for me (the same result seems also easier to obtain):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
# the following two libraries are needed only if you execute the code outside the Python Console (for example, from the Processing Toolbox)
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

map_settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
c = QgsComposition(QgsProject.instance())
c.setPaperSize(420, 297) #width and height (in mm) for the A3 format

view = iface.openComposer(c)

composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, 0 ,0, 420, 297)
# where the second and third parameters are customizable offsets (in mm) for positioning the composition (setting both 0 as values means that the rendering will start from the upper left corner of the composition)
# and the fourth and fifth parameters are the width and the height (in mm) for the A3 format
composerMap.setBackgroundEnabled(True)

rect = QgsRectangle(map_settings.fullExtent())
composerMap.setNewExtent(rect)
composerMap.updateItem()
c.addComposerMap(composerMap)
```

---

Please note that my answer gives a solution for your question as it has been asked, i.e. *creating a new print composer programmatically for A3 page format*. If you want a more specific solution (for example adding files from the outside, legends, labels, scale bars and so on), I suggest asking a new separate question for each issue for the sake of clearness.

Comment: okay, i deleted my answer because it was just two lines more and also from a script. so, if you want it to execute from a script, just add "from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface" in the beginning.

Comment: @DirkBrunken, thanks. I add the missing libraries in the code.

Comment: Creating a new print composer with one map containing all enabled layers is a great idea. Unfortunately, the posted code doesn't work here in QGIS 3.x master: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: QgsComposition(QgsMapSettings, QgsProject): not enough arguments` I've already replaced PyQt4 in PyQt5.

Comment: @LunarSea You didn't mention it in your question... I will try to edit my answer by adding a working code for QGIS 3, though.

Comment: I've installed QGIS 3.x for testing and bug reporting purposes yesterday. Unfortunately, I had to deinstall QGIS 2.18 first :/

Comment: I can test the code at weekend, but I suppose it works fine! So I've already upvoted and accepted your answer. It's great to see, that the QGIS 3.x solution is quite simple.

Comment: @LunarSea It worked for me and I'm sure it will work also for you. Therefore, thanks for the bounty, I really appreciated. If you find some issues, please report them here and I will try to give a solution. Instead, if you want to perform any additional task (adding legends, labels, scalebar and so on), I think the best would be asking a new separate question since the issue here is only related to the creation of a print composer.

Comment: @mgri - QGIS 3 does seem to make PyQGIS code more concise, nice one! :)

Comment: @mgri The code for 2.x works as expected, but I get an error message for the 3.x version in QGIS master 313ec55: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: QgsComposition(QgsMapSettings, QgsProject): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsProject' `

Comment: @LunarSea Hmm, weird... Does it change something if you add `from qgis.core import QgsComposition, QgsProject` at the beginning of the code?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, perhaps there is an issue with the installation.

Comment: @LunarSea I have just run a test and it worked for me. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBGjX.gif) (it also works if there are some loaded layers).